# JQuery Button Toggle issue when the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I started improvising one of my old websites, but have stuck up on a jquery problem. I have created a button which shows up when the width of the browser is less than 768px, by using bootstrap "visible-xs" class. Using jQuery I tried to hide the data when the browser size is less than 768px. All-together, when the browser is less than or "RESIZED" less than 768px, the button will appear and the data hides. When clicked on the button the data should toggle using slideToggle. But the problem here is that I'm not able to toggle the data.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $(".toggle-this").hide();
      $(".show-hide-button").click(function() {
        $(".toggle-this").slideToggle(500);
      });
    } else {
      $(".toggle-this").show();
    }
  });
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(".toggle-this").hide();
    $(".show-hide-button").click(function() {
      $(".toggle-this").slideToggle(500);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-hide-button visible-xs">Show More</button>

<div class="toggle-this">
  Lorem ipsum dolor ...
</div>
```

Written the `$(window).width() < 768px` outside the resize function also cause the data hides when the browser is resized but when it is refreshed the data appears back. The slideToggle doesn't seem to have any effect on the code.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: You forgot to add `.` before `show-hide-button` class

Comment: @ManishPatel Thank you. I've been trying to find the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax error in your `jquery` selector. You can find correct code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(".toggle-this").hide();
            $(".show-hide-button").click(function() {
                $(".toggle-this").slideToggle(500);
            });
        } else {
            $(".toggle-this").show();
        }
    });
   if ($(window).width() < 768) {
       $(".toggle-this").hide();
       $(".show-hide-button").click(function() {
          $(".toggle-this").slideToggle(500);
       });
   }
});
```

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-hide-button visible-xs">Show More</button>
<div class="toggle-this">Lorem ipsum dolor ...</div>
```

Comment: @AbhishekF, if my answer solve your problem then please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 2 things here:

1. You are binding `click` event every time on the `$(".show-hide-button")` button when browser is resizing. This will cause multiple event binding on the
   same button. So, keep the show/hide part in after resize for that matter and shift the event binding outside of it and do it once only (may be on document ready).
2. You should not show/hide this with jQuery/JavaScript. CSS media query is enough for this. Enough classes in *bootstrap* are written already. Try this:

   Try this code:

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-hide-button visible-xs" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">Show More</button>

   <div class="toggle-this collapse" id="collapseExample">
     Lorem ipsum dolor ...
   </div>


   $(document).ready(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
     $('#collapseExample').removeClass('in')
   }
   ```

   });

See this here on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/